# Update Linkedin Company Profile via API with PHP?

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

Is this possible? It's driving me crazy. I cannot find any resources about it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

No. Unfortunately, you can't update profiles via the API. :(